# How to remove both the prefix and file extension from url in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I currently have htaccess rules in place which will redirect all the website traffic to a URL without any prefix. So for example:

www.mywebsite.com -> mywebsite.com

Now I want to include a rule that also strips the .html extensions from the URL so thatthe URL prefix, any file extensions and "index.html" are being removed. So for example:

www.mywebsite.com/index.html -> mywebsite.com

www.mywebsite.com/contact.html -> mywebsite.com/contact

The code I have in place looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

How would I add a rule that removes both the prefix, the .html extension and "index.html"?

Comment: Do you want to remove www. from site url ? and .html from file ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So for example: www.mywebsite.com/index.html -> mywebsite.com

Comment: Actually you contradict yourself. The example you gave with ``index.html`` does _not_ only remove the ".html" file name extension...

Comment: Ah, I should have been more clear. I want to remove both the prefix and the .html extension as I showed in my example

Answer (score 0):

1. REMOVING THE WWW PREFIX FROM DOMAIN URLS

   ```
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```
2. To remove .html extension use:

   ```
   #remove html file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.html will become https://example.com/file
   RewriteEngine on 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
   ```
3. Remove index.html

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
   ```

Comment: I should have been more clear. I want to remove both the prefix and the .html extension as I showed in my example. So, one set of rules that will do this:

www.mywebsite.com/index.html -> mywebsite.com

Comment: Thanks for the update. The only thing now is that these 3 separate sets need to be combined into 1 set of rules I can put in my htaccess file.  Is something like that possible?